# ADT Plugin Directory Location for SDK - (MotoDev)

Tags: eclipse, sdk, adt, motodev-studio

Right now I am setting up Motodev. 
Its a Android Development Suite built on Eclipse, created by Motorola.

What is needed is the Android SDK. Check, got that, newest version, everything is set with that.

Now it says I need the ADT Eclipse plugin. Version 20.0.1, currently mine is v18.

I know where to get it, I can easily get it, but I am curious, where should it be installed? Currently I dont have eclipse I am just using MotoDev. But since Motodev asks where the SDK location is, and says my ADT plugin is out of date, I am assuming I have to install the ADT in the SDK directory. But is there somewhere more specific to put it? In a specific folder? or just in the top level of the SDK directory?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use ADT20 with MOTODEV Studio 4.0. The plugins had some API changes between 18 and 20 that made them incompatible with each other. You will need to roll your SDK back to 19 until we can release a newer version.  I wrote about this about a week ago on the [MOTODEV Studio blog](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android-Blog/MOTODEV-Studio-4-0-and-the-ADT-20-plugins/ba-p/27710).

We're done with the engineering work on the new version.  It's just a matter of getting the push to the web server scheduled.  I expect it to be ready by late next week or early the following week.

Until then, if you need to use ADT20 for Jellybean development, use [Eclipse for Mobile Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) plus the MOTODEV Core Plugins (using *Help>Eclipse Marketplace*).  Most of the functionality of the installed product is there, but without the dependency on ADT.  See the blog for details on how to set that up.